# how can get the keys of a Map(json) in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In javascript I used

```
Object.keys(data["fields"]) -->  data["fields"] is a json={key1:1,key2:2...}
```

and returned the keys of my json. I'm looking for equivalence the flutter.

I had trying

but it doesn't seem to work

```
for (var field in data["fields"]) {
 print(field);
```

}

how can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  Map map = {"k1":"v1", "k2":"v2","k3":"v3"}; 

  map.forEach((k,v)=>print(k)); // prints k1 k2 k3
```

Answer (score 1):

`Map` has a `keys` getter that returns an iterator of the keys. (The default implementation of `Map` is a `LinkedHashMap`, so the order is insertion order.)

You can use that to create a list of the keys or use it as an iterator.

```
  var map = <int, String>{
    1: 'one',
    2: 'two',
    3: 'three',
  };
  print(map.keys.toList()); // a list of the keys
  map.keys.forEach(print); // or just use the iterator directly
```